# Query max Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, max

I have a query that result 2 data(s) with the same employee

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables->select('a.employee_id, a.name, b.employee_position');
->from('employee a')
->join('employee_position b','b.employee_id = .a.employee_id AND `b`.`deleted`=0 AND `c`.`date_start` <= "'.$now_date.'"','inner')
$data = $this->datatables->get_adata();
$aaData = $data->aaData;
```

I wan't only one data appear which is choosing the max data on date_start column, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in your code:

```
$this->db->order_by('c.date_start', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(1, 1);
```